# Detection of noise and outliers

Tags: distributions, outliers, noise

I am measuring the number of cells with a mutation in a series of 106 subjects. For each position of the genome, the method will output the total number of cells analysed and the number of cells with a specific nucleotide at that position (i.e. how many with A, with T, with G or with C). For each subject, at each genome position I find that most cells have a single nucleotide, so that its frequency is close to 100%. **I am interested in understanding if the low frequency of the other nucleotides is real (thus constituting a potential pathogenic mutation) or due to errors.**

The method has a certain degree of error (unknown, likely influenced by many factors and thus not controllable) which may result, for example, in calling a cell with A rather than the correct value of C. As an example, If I plot the frequency of each nucleotide (y-axis, in %) seen for a specific position across all subjects (x-axis is the series of subjects) I obtain the following graph.

[image]

Red line indicates the median of the frequency for that nucleotide at that position, the green line represents the median + 3*MAD.

If we look at the panel for A, **is there a way to understand whether the subjects with a frequency above the green line are outliers, and to assign a p-value to them?** My idea is that the smaller peaks are indeed noise due to technical errors, which could be modeled and used to identify outliers (true mutations).

Focusing on the frequencies of A, if we do an histogram we obtain the following:

[image]

It is not a normal distribution, it has been suggested to follow a Poisson distribution. **Is there a way to fit a Poisson distribution to this specific dataset and then calculate the probability to see such outliers (sort of a p-value)?** In this case, the outliers could be the subjects in bins at 0.09 and 0.14. I know a little bit of R, so it would be great to know if is there a way to use R to analyse the data set to look for outliers.

Additional questions:
1) Would you approach this analysis differently? How?
2) Barplots may not be the best way to represent these data (see first figure), in this case, which graph would you recommend?

Thanks a lot for your help and insight!